# Is it possible to define a type for property names in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

So i have this constants `class` which defines the names of the variables that i save to the `localStorage` / `chrome.storage` and what their default value is if the items doesn't exist in the storage.

**SettingsConstants.ts**

```
export class SettingsConstants {
  public static SETTINGS_ALLOWED: string = "settingsAllowed";
  public static QUIT_ALLOWED: string = "quitAllowed";

  public static DEFAULTS: any = () => {
    const defaults = {};
    defaults[SettingsConstant.SETTINGS_ALLOWED] = true;
    defaults[SettingsConstant.QUIT_ALLOWED] = true;
    return defaults;
  };

  public static STORAGE_STRINGS: string[] = [
      SettingsConstant.SETTINGS_ALLOWED,
      SettingsConstant.QUIT_ALLOWED
    ]
}
```

Then i have `SettingsService` which uses these constants in the `getItemsFromStorage()` method. Basically what it does is that it loops through the strings defined in `SettingsConstants` and sets it own `properties` equal to the `value` it got from the `storage`, otherwise set the default `value`.

**SettingsService.ts**

```
export class SettingsService implements ISettingsService {

  private settingsAllowed: boolean = undefined;
  private quitAllowed: boolean = undefined;

   constructor(logger: Logger) {
     this.logger = logger;
     this.getItemsFromStorage();
   }

   private getItemsFromStorage(): void {
    const storageStrings: string[] = SettingsConstant.STORAGE_STRINGS;
    for (let i = 0; i < storageStrings.length; i++) {
      const currentString = storageStrings[i];
      if (!this.hasOwnProperty(currentString)) {
        throw "The property is not defined, " +
        "check if it matches the STORAGE_STRING in SettingsConstants";
      }
      const currentItem = this.getItem(currentString);
      this[currentString] = currentItem === undefined
        ? SettingsConstant.DEFAULTS()[currentString]
        : currentItem;
      this.logger.log(currentString, "=", this[currentString]);
    }
  }

  private getItem(item: any): any {
    const localItem: string = localStorage.getItem(item);
    if (localItem === undefined || localItem === null || localItem === 'undefined') {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(localItem);
    }
  }
}
```

The code works, but it isn't statically checked, which is what i desire. The current way to check if `SettingsService` has a `property` is to set the `property` to `undefined` then use

```
if (!this.hasOwnProperty(currentString)) {
    throw "The property is not defined, " +
    "check if it matches the STORAGE_STRING in SettingsConstants";
}
```

To check if the variable exists in the `class`, if it doesn't then it must mean that we might have misspelled it, or forgotten to add it.

I could solve this problem by adding them to the `ISettingsService` `interface`, that would however mean that the `property` would become `public` which is not the intention

**My desired solution**

I would like to define a type where i could define the names of the variables that were allowed to be used. Similar to this

```
export declare namespace SettingsTypes{
  type SettingsType = "settingsAllowed" | "quitAllowed";
}
```

Then in `SettingsService` i could write the following

```
private settingsAllowed: SettingsTypes.SettingType: boolean;
```

So its like `settingsAllowed` name has to be of type `SettingsTypes.SettingType` and its return type would be `boolean`

However this does not seem to make much sense, and it seems like there is no way to do this properly, so i was wondering if any of you bright heads might have a great solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an interesting question. I went to read some documentation. Have a look at the section of the type guards in particular. Perhaps you can do something similar where you do a type guard for boolean?

```
function isSetting(setting: any): setting is Settings {
return typeof  setting === SettingsTypes.SettingType;
}
```

Something similar to this. It’s just a possible idea

[Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: It only works for functions, and not for property names.

Comment: OK. Point taken. Doesn’t it still simplify your code?

Comment: I'd need to check on the name of the property and check if it was of type SettingsType and checking the property name isn't so trivial if it is simple types like string or number. I think i'll just go with defining them as undefined. Its not pretty but it seems to be the best solution

Comment: Sometimes you need to do with the best possible solution. It’s not always possible to make it nice and pretty and by the book :)